# After the app crashes , will be there my saved data

Tags: ios, core-data

I am new to core data. Using managedObjectContext i saved some data to core data. But after i stop running the application and running the app next time, my already saved data is not there.

So will it be the same situation when my app crashes? Will all the data be lost? What should i do to keep the data safe whatever happens.

all advices appreciated.thanks in advance

Comment: What is a crash log or on which function does it stop ?

Comment: how are you saving it?

Comment: [self.managedobjectcontext save:&error];

Comment: i am stopping the app by myself. But once again when i run the app, the data isnt there. My question is, is this the same situation when the app crashes.

Comment: can you please post some code snippet and at which stage you have stopped application to run.

Comment: NSManagedObject *shrt=[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Shirt" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedobjectcontext];
    [shrt setValue:shrttxt1.text forKey:@"shirtname"];
    [shrt setValue:shrttxt2.text forKey:@"brandname"];
    
    NSError *error;
    [managedobjectcontext save:&error];

Comment: Are you checking that the save has occured without an error?

Answer (score 0):

It depends, if App crash after saving your data. then your data is saved. But if it crash while saving your data. then there is no guarantee. Whether your data is saved or not.

Comment: 'NSManagedObject *shrt=[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Shirt" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedobjectcontext];
    [shrt setValue:shrttxt1.text forKey:@"shirtname"];
    [shrt setValue:shrttxt2.text forKey:@"brandname"];
    
    NSError *error;
    [managedobjectcontext save:&error];'